# Mail hosting from Cpanel to bluehost?

Tags: email, cpanel

I have domain with little space with Cpanel , But Now I have  new hosting with unlimited space , So I need to keep web-site but I want transfer Email host to new hosting  . I successfully assign my domain to new host But I cannot change MX records to my new Hosting ?

Answer (score 2):

The first, You should edit Refer DNS to new hosting.
The second, You should configure Mail hosting again.
Good luck!

Comment: thank you --- more details please , in my bluehost i assign domain successfully to my account and in my cpanel tried to  ma mx record but not work